# how can we connect MYSQL with html

Tags: html, sql, database

i want to connect my data base with html web side please tell me how can i connect the html website to MY SQL.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Questions on StackOverflow should be detailed, researched, and you should show what you've tried. Take a look at the How to ask a good question faq here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: HTML is a markup language just like an XML file. It don't have such capabilities. HTML is not supposed to do such things. It's just a way of presenting a document.

Comment: You can connect the HTML + javaScript to some backend, like an ASP.NET, PHP, or Azure Functions. With WebAssembly, in the future it will be possible to connect directly from the WebBrowser to the MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **PHP** and setup a **Localhost webserver**, something like **Wamp** or **Xamp** will do.
I personally use Wamp, you can make a Database in the PhpMyAdmin service provided with it.

To further setup and connect to your database, you can simply search on google for some more detailed steps regarding to database connections.

but using a local webserver and php should get you up and running.

Comment: `You need to use PHP` This is false :). _One option_ is to use php, that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backend script/service to achieve the goal. You cant make connection directly. In between database and frontend (your html pages) there is backend.
to achieve your goal you can use php, node js which has n number of tutorials available.
Your question is getting minus points because it is incomplete and very basic. 
Thanks